# Cisco VPN Connection - No internet no nothing

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-vpn

Sorry if this has been posted, I tried searching but I am not exactly sure what I am looking for, I am a developer not a networking guy.

We have a client whom we need to use Cisco VPN client to connect to their servers. I have installed the software, dropped in the provided .pcf file, and I can connect. However, when I do, I lose all local and internet capabilities, no hosts resolve, and I still can't connect to their internal FTP and development sites.

This leads me to believe either a setting is wrong in my Cisco software, and/or their network is not correctly configured.

Does anyone know anything about Cisco VPN'ing that can give me a hand? My colleague seems to indicate that they need to enable split tunneling on their end (or a similar setting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because they have turned off [split tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunnel) in the Cisco client.  You can go into the options of the VPN connection and try to enable it again.  Depending on how bad they have locked it down, you might be able to turn on split tunneling, if not, the option will be greyed out.

EDIT: You can also try the manual override suggestion from [here](http://forums.speedguide.net/showthread.php?t=209167).  Look at the 3rd post down on the page.  Basically it is telling you how to change your routing table after logging into the VPN.
/EDIT

Basically what is happening is that the VPN client is routing all of your traffic through the VPN.  Some admins think that increases the security of their people when on the road.  In my experience, it just causes other problems, such as the one your having.

Comment: Thank you. I am using version 5.0.04.0300, I don't see an option to enable split tunneling, though?

Comment: What does it show here:  Go to Status > Statistics > Tunnel Details.  Look for Local LAN Access.

Comment: It says 'Local Lan Access: Disabled' - even if I enable it, it still says Disabled.

Comment: That sounds like the Cisco admin has disabled your ability to do split tunnel, so you will have to do the manual method outlined in my EDIT above.

Comment: Gotcha. He changed some settings, and I can browse the internet after connecting, but now no traffic is sent over VPN. There are two entries for the same IP in the route table, and I deleted one and still no go.

Comment: Can you post the output of "route print" and also tell me which is local LAN and which is the VPN you are trying to connect to?

Comment: I'll get a snapshot Monday when I am back at my desk.